# Algorithm for merge data of related struct fields

Tags: rust, collections, merge

Given the next collection:

`let unmerged: Vec<T> = [... some T instances ...];`

where `T` it's defined as follows:

```
pub struct T {
    name: String,
    other: HashMap<String, Other>
}
```

and Other:

```
pub struct Other {
    name: String
}
```

I want to merge all the elements of type T that has the same value on it's `name` field into only once instance of `T`, and append the rest of the values on the HashMap of the rest of elements with the same value on the `name` field to that only unique instance, so finally, I would have something like:

```
let merged: Vec<T> = [
    ... some T instances ...
];
```

where every instances has a unique value on it's `name` field, and the HashMap contains all entries found on the elements of the `unmerged` collection where the `name` it's the same.

What would be the more effective aproach to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It's a little confusing that both structs are called `T`. What is the result of the merged T in the vector? Is it the first or second struct T? Or is it just a `Vec<HashMap<String, Other>>`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, misspelled the struct's name.
Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to approach this would be to build up a `HashMap<String, T>` and then collect the values into a `Vec<T>` at the end:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry as HashMapEntry;

// Renamed from T, because T is more commonly used to denote a generic type.
struct Entry {
    pub name: String,
    pub other: HashMap<String, Other>,
}

struct Other {
    pub name: String,
}

fn merge_duplicate_entries(it: impl IntoIterator<Item=Entry>) -> Vec<Entry> {
    let mut result: HashMap<String, Entry> = HashMap::new();
    
    for entry in it {
        // We can't use and_modify/or_insert here since both will want to move
        // all or part of entry, so we have to do this a bit more manually.
        match result.entry(entry.name.clone()) {
            HashMapEntry::Occupied(mut e) => {
                e.get_mut().other.extend(entry.other.into_iter());
            }
            HashMapEntry::Vacant(e) => { e.insert(entry); }
        }
    }
    
    result.into_values().collect()
}
```

This should be pretty straightforward.  Note that when our `result` map already contains the name of an entry, we can use `.extend()` to dump the contents of `Entry::other` into the existing entry all at once.  At the end, there will be exactly one `Entry` value for a given string, and we can collect the values into a vector.

Note that if there are two `Entry` values with the same name, and their respective `other` maps each have an entry with the same key, the second one encountered will overwrite the first.